# Node JS - Firestore get() response is never called

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm setting up a simple server with nodejs with Firestore admin connection, already setup the connection, but when i call

```
dbFB.collection('users').get()
.then((response) => {
})
.catch((err) => {
})
```

the whole function looks like this:

```
function userExist(name) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        var dbFB = initializeApp();

        var result = dbFB.collection('users').get().then((response) => {

            var snap = response.docs;
            console.log('snap', snap);

            if (!snap.empty) {
                snap.forEach((doc) => {

                    console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());

                    if (name == doc.data().name) {
                        console.log('foreach');
                        resolve(doc.data().idFB);
                    }

                });
            }

            reject("User does no exist");

        })
        .catch((err) => {

            console.log('Error getting documents', err);
            reject(err);

        })

    });
}
```

Here i trigger the userExist function =>

```
const self = module.exports = {
    configureUsers: function (name) {
        return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

            console.log(`Name: ${name}`);

            const userResponse = userExist(name);
            userResponse.then((user) => {

                    console.log('Begin promise USEREXIST');

                    if (user != "") {

                        console.log(`idFB: ${user}`);

                        let users = [];

                        // wipe users
                        db.set('users', {}).write();

                        users.push(user);

                        db.set(`users[${user}]`, {
                            keyFilePath: path.resolve(__dirname, `configurations/secrets/omni.json`),
                            savedTokensPath: path.resolve(__dirname, `configurations/tokens/${user}.json`)
                        }).write()

                        resolve(db.getState())

                        console.log("User exists");

                        rl.close();
                    }
                    reject('User does not exists');
                    rl.close();

                })
                .catch((err) => {

                    console.log("Closing Catch");
                    reject(err);
                    rl.close();

                })
        });
    }
}
```

i never get a response either in Then or Catch, already check the firebase app is initialized, with all the parameters so no idea what could be wrong here.

Something weird is that in Firebase project usage appears the count of read calls, it takes a while to appear, but it appear..

any ideas?

Comment: Does the function itself not need to be async? `async function userExist...`. Also... have you thought about using `async await` to make the asynchronous stuff a lot easier to deal with (and read). :D

Comment: @Fogmeister along with the Promise? or use async instead of Promise return?

Comment: Hmm... TBH I'm not entirely sure. We use async await everywhere so not entirely sure of the exact process with Promises. What is the trigger of this function?

Comment: @Fogmeister give it a look, just add the trigger function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, actually, was a newbie mistake, node js was outdated, i updated it and firebase start working perfectly,

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick

```
const userExist = async (name) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        var dbFB = initializeApp();

        var result = dbFB.collection('users').get().then((response) => {

            var snap = response.docs;
            console.log('snap', snap);

            if (!snap.empty) {
                snap.forEach((doc) => {

                    console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());

                    if (name == doc.data().name) {
                        console.log('foreach');
                        resolve(doc.data().idFB);
                    }

                });
            }

            reject("User does no exist");

        })
        .catch((err) => {

            console.log('Error getting documents', err);
            reject(err);

        })

    });
}
```

Then you implement it like this (for example):

```
(async () => {
   const data = await userExist(WHATEVER)

})()
```

BUT BUT BUT... since you have the name, you dont need to query the whole collection as you are doing... so something like this maybe could work better...

```
const userExist = async (name) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        var dbFB = initializeApp();

        var result = dbFB.collection('users')
                     .where(`name`, `==`, name) // <-- here
                     .get().then((response) => {

            var snap = response.docs;
            console.log('snap', snap);

            if (!snap.empty) {
                snap.forEach((doc) => {

                    console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());

                    if (name == doc.data().name) {
                        console.log('foreach');
                        resolve(doc.data().idFB);
                    }

                });
            }

            reject("User does no exist");

        })
        .catch((err) => {

            console.log('Error getting documents', err);
            reject(err);

        })

    });
}
```

Comment: great approach but sadly same result :( it stucks in dbFB.collection('users').get(); it doesn't do anything after calling get(), it simply die there, it doesn't enter on then or catch

Answer (score 1):

I would modify this, as others have said, to be async rather than rely on promises. Give something like this a shot:

```
async function userExist(name) {
    try 
    {
        const dbFB = initializeApp(); // this should probably get moved outside
        const collectionRef = await dbFB.collection('users').get();
        if (collectionRef && collectionRef.length > 0) {
            collectionRef.forEach((docRef) => {
                console.log(docRef.id, '=>', docRef.data());
                if (name == doc.data().name) {
                   console.log('foreach');
                   return doc.data().idFB;
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
    }
}
```

Comment: Same result :( it stucks in dbFB.collection('users').get(); it doesn't do anything after calling get(), it simply die there